# XMLHttpRequest: Read text file into a matrix

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, readfile

I would like to read a text file with numbers and put them into a matrix with XMHLHttpRequest

I've already used the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), but for some reason when I used it, my application had some graphical bugs.

My idea is to get the numbers on the text file and use with Babylon.js so I can plot points into the canvas.

File Example:

```
NUM_GRUPOS 1
[GRUPO]
TAM 64
[PONTOS]
ROTULO 1
 2.50000000000000E+0002 -2.00000000000000E+0002  2.00000000000000E+0001  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  1.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000
ROTULO 2
 3.54000000000000E+0002 -2.52000000000000E+0002  3.90000000000000E+0002  1.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000  0.00000000000000E+0000
... //A bunch of other numbers
[ARESTAS]
TAM 60
 2.50000000000000E+0002-2.00000000000000E+0002 2.00000000000000E+0001 3.09941176470588E+0002-1.59941176470588E+0002 8.58823529411765E+0001 0.00000000000000E+0000 0.00000000000000E+0000 1.00000000000000E+0000
```

[Complete example](http://pastebin.com/VH6H9AMb)

I want to skip all these first lines and start reading from the ***[ARESTAS]*** keyword or ***TAM*** keyword and put the numbers into a matrix[n][9], where n is the number of lines after the keyword

The first six numbers represents a coordinate (x, y, z) in the canvas, the last three represents the object color

This is what I did with the FileReader:

```
var matrix = [];
var keyWord = '[ARESTAS]';
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    function readSingleFile(evt) {
        var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

        if (f) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            var contents = 'empty';
            r.onload = function(e) { 
                contents = e.target.result;
                var pastKey = false;
                contents.split('\n').forEach(function(line, i) {
                  if (pastKey) {
                    var vals = line.trim().split(' ');
                    if (vals.length > 2) {
                      matrix.push(vals);
                    }

                  }
                  if (line.trim() === keyWord) {
                    pastKey = true;
                  }

                })
            }
        r.readAsText(f);
        } else { 
            alert("Failed");
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why iterate lines?

```
        r.onload = function(e) {
            contents = e.target.result;
            var pos = contents.indexOf(keyWord) + keyWord.length; //find [ARESTAS] portion
            var numbers = contents.substr(pos).trim(); //trim it from rest of file
            matrix = numbers.split('\n') // get separate lines
                .map(function (e) {
                    return e.split(' '); // split them by whitespace
                })
                .filter(function (e) {
                    return e.length > 2; // filter all unwanted lines
                })
        }
```

... or even:

```
    function readMatrix(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            var pos = contents.indexOf(keyWord) + keyWord.length; //find [ARESTAS] portion

            var matrix = contents
                .substr(pos) // get arestas section
                .trim(); //trim redundant whitespace
                .split('\n') // get separate lines
                .slice(1) // skip TAM ### line
                .map(function (e) {
                    return e.split(' '); // split separate lines by whitespace
                }); // get final matrix

            callback(matrix); // pass received data to callback
        }
        xhr.send();
    }

    document.getElementById('fileinput')
        .addEventListener('change', function () {

            var url = ... address of file

            ...

            readMatrix(function (matrix) {

               // we got filled matrix here

            });
        }, false);
```

Comment: My JavaScript knowledge is kinda poor. Can I ask you to explain what exactly you're doing on each solution, or can you provide a functional demo?

Answer (score 0):

Can try this as start point

```
    var start = contents.indexOf('[ARESTAS]');
    // get rid of all before ARESTAS, then split and remove first 2 rows
    var txtArr = txt.slice(start).split('\r\n').splice(2);
    //trim and  split each line at space and map to array of numbers
    var numArr = txtArr.reduce(function(a, c){
      a.push(c.trim().split(' ').map(Number))
      return a
    },[])
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EglSDbvG8oCsfSUAgCyd?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: That works pretty well, but in my case, the text file need to be loaded from an URL or by selecting the file on the computer. Not from a local file on my computer, if you understand

Comment: load the file any way you want.... I was showing how to convert it to array. But if you look at my demo it is loaded from url also (data.txt on left)

Comment: I tried using the same code you provided, but it returns this error: 
syntax error TestCluster.s3d:1:1
syntax error index.html:1:1

This testcluster.s3d is my text file. When I try to show the array on console, it shows it's empty

Comment: Update demo with actual content used that throws that error

Comment: For some reason, on the demo it doesn't happens. When I run my index on my browser it shows. Now the other problem is when I try to load the file using the button, it shows that `TypeError: txt.indexOf is not a function`